# How to copy **argv to a new variable?

Tags: c, memcpy

I want to make a copy of a variable such as `char **argv` using something like memcpy but how? can I know the size and how to parameterize it since `memcpy` doesn't take a two-star as a parameter. Do I have to write a loop?

I have to build up the pipeline before I execute it. Therefore I want to "spawn" variables like `argv` in every iteration of the loop.

```
    token = strtok(cmd, "|");
    i = 0;
    while (token != NULL)
    {   
        printf("token %s\n", token);       
        makeArgs(token, &argc, &argv);
        for (int b = 0; b < argc; b++) {
           printf("makeargs %d: %s\n", b, argv[b]);   
        }   

        // Will copy argc characters from array1 to array2
       /* memcpy(makearg,argc, argc*18*sizeof(int));*/    
        shellcommand[i].argv = argv;
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, "|");
    }           
   /* do stuff */
   fork_pipes(argc, shellcommand);
```

My aim is to build up the pipeline like the following.

```
/*  who | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n */
static char *cmd0[] = { "who",                0 };
static char *cmd1[] = { "awk",  "{print $1}", 0 };
static char *cmd2[] = { "sort",               0 };
static char *cmd3[] = { "uniq", "-c",         0 };
static char *cmd4[] = { "sort", "-n",         0 };

static char **cmds[] = { cmd0, cmd1, cmd2, cmd3, cmd4 };
```

Comment: `argv` is an array of pointers to null-terminated strings of size `argc`.

Comment: Because argv[] stores pointers to C strings, perhaps a string copy function would be of more use to you...  If you just want to store the pointer, char**temp = argv.  To store the internals, a loop with string copies to a nice home would be recommended.

Comment: @milleniumbug: Size `argc+1`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Oh right, since `argv[argc] == NULL`.

Comment: But I can't copy it just like it were a char array can I?

Comment: @Programmer400 Well, yeah, you can't copy it like a char array, because it's not a char array.

Comment: A double pointer *is* a single pointer.  You can apply `memcpy()` to it.  It's merely a question of whether the result is in fact what you really want, and you haven't been clear about what that is.

Comment: Also, if you need to pass it to some function, check if you really need to make a deep copy, or only pass a pointer, since often frameworks only read `argv` and don't modify it.

Comment: @milleniumbug I'm in a loop and need to make a pipeline where for ech command in the pipeline, the local argv is the arguments. So I must make a copy in each iteration.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I want to re-use argv while keeping the copy.

Comment: Or, loop through each command embedded within the current argv and execute in a switch statement of some sort depending on the value.  Then, no need to copy...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I have to build up the pipeline before I execute it. I can post my function.

Comment: Ok, then a for loop from i=1; i < argc, get size with str len, make buffer, copy.  Skip argv[0] as that is the executable name.

Comment: That will only copy argv[0] I am pretty sure.  Loop each value and you have something.

Comment: Now it works. I used the code from the answer by @milleniumbug

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code makes a deep copy of `argv`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // allocate memory and copy strings
    char** new_argv = malloc((argc+1) * sizeof *new_argv);
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        size_t length = strlen(argv[i])+1;
        new_argv[i] = malloc(length);
        memcpy(new_argv[i], argv[i], length);
    }
    new_argv[argc] = NULL;

    // do operations on new_argv
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", new_argv[i]);
    }

    // free memory
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        free(new_argv[i]);
    }
    free(new_argv);
}
```

Comment: Ok fine, give him the solution then :)

Comment: You could use `strdup()` instead of `malloc()` plus `memcpy()` to make it 2 lines shorter. 8-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to pointer from @milleniumbug I made a version that returns only one pointer, and is thus easier to pass across instance or thread boundaries and also to free after use. Without your hint I would not have had a thread safe way.

```
char **copy_argv(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // calculate the contiguous argv buffer size
  int length=0;
  for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  {
      length += (strlen(argv[i]) + 1);
  }
  char** new_argv = (char**)malloc((argc + 1) * sizeof(char*) + length);
  // copy argv into the contiguous buffer
  length = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  {
      new_argv[i] = &(((char*)new_argv)[argc * sizeof(char*) + length]);
      strcpy(new_argv[i], argv[i]);
      length = (strlen(argv[i]) + 1);
  }
  new_argv[argc] = NULL;
  return(new_argv);
}
```

This single pointer-structure is an immutable I guess, and easier to copy.

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution by @conrad-b because it lays out memory in one contiguous block. However, there are a couple of bugs in it.

- `new_argv[i] = &(((char*)new_argv)[argc * sizeof(char*) + length]);` will start writing argv[0] data where the terminating NULL ptr will later be written. So new_argv[0] will have its first 4 or 8 bytes zero'd out.
- `length = (strlen(argv[i]) + 1);` should be a += operation.

So the final solution should look more like this:

```cpp
char **copy_argv(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // calculate the contiguous argv buffer size
  int length=0;
  size_t ptr_args = argc + 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  {
    length += (strlen(argv[i]) + 1);
  }
  char** new_argv = (char**)malloc((ptr_args) * sizeof(char*) + length);
  // copy argv into the contiguous buffer
  length = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  {
    new_argv[i] = &(((char*)new_argv)[(ptr_args * sizeof(char*)) + length]);
    strcpy(new_argv[i], argv[i]);
    length += (strlen(argv[i]) + 1);
  }
  // insert NULL terminating ptr at the end of the ptr array
  new_argv[ptr_args-1] = NULL;
  return (new_argv);
}
```